# Facebook Auto Post to Page Programatically via Cron

Tags: facebook

I've created a Facebook app with the purpose to post to my Facebook Page via cron. It is based on the code provided here: http://www.devhour.net/automatically-post-page-using-php-facebook-sdk/

When I execute the PHP script via browser, I receive the following error message:

(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Any ideas? App only posts to page that I'm an admin. Does it still have to reviewed and approved by Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The error usually means that you did not authorize with the correct permissions. Debug your Access Token and see if publish_pages is available: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You do not need to go through the review process if only you are using the App. Permissions work without review for App Admins/Developers/Testers.

Btw, that article is from 2013, you should use the Facebook docs for reference instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

Comment: Yeah, used a more recent article, and got it working Next hurdle: to post as page instead as admin. No luck.

Comment: you just need to use a page token and the publish_pages permission ;)

Comment: docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish